# How to compile existing posix code for 64-bit Windows?

Tags: 64-bit, cygwin, mingw, win64

I'm ok with using Cygwin or MinGW, but I need to end up with 64-bit code, not 32-bit.  This is because I will be calling the DLL from 64-bit managed C#.  I can't seem to find and good references for setting up those tools to create 64-bit binaries.  Also, it would be nice if the GCC was version 4, not version 3 as came with my Cygwin install.

An alternative would be some form of interprocess communication.  I will research that, but what I laid out above is what I really want.

Comment: I found a Ming64 windows build at http://www.drangon.org/mingw/ that seemed like it was about to work.  There were no issues with header files not found, etc.  But then cc1plus.exe (called by g++) crashed.  Sigh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [64-bit MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64), based on (just released) gcc-4.4.0, is probably your best bet.
(Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org it's better to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org))

Detailed instructions:
1. Download the [archive](http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=202880&filename=mingw-w64-bin_i686-cygwin-1.5.25-15_20090514.tar.bz2&a=93736319)
2. Extract it somewhere under cygwin. In my case, top-level cygwin directory is `C:\cygwin`, I extracted the package into `mingw` directory, and ended up with the following contents in `C:\cygwin\mingw` (which is visible as `/mingw` under cygwin:

```
$ ls -l /mingw
total 1
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 user None  0 May 10 08:32 bin
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 user None  0 May 10 05:45 include
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 user None  0 May 10 08:30 info
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 user None  0 May 10 08:30 lib
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 user None  0 May 10 05:45 libexec
drwxr-xr-x+ 4 user None  0 May 10 05:45 man
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user None 17 May 17 17:20 mingw -> x86_64-pc-mingw32
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 user None  0 May 10 04:16 share
drwxr-xr-x+ 5 user None  0 May 10 04:18 x86_64-pc-mingw32
```

3. Now compile some C++ code. I used:

```
// t.cc
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> vs;
    vs.push_back("abc");
}
```

And compile it like this:

```
$ /mingw/bin/x86_64-pc-mingw32-g++ t.cc
```

4. Finally, verify the result is a Windows/x 64 executable, by running `dumpbin /headers a.exe`:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 7.00.9466
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file a.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (AMD64)
              10 number of sections
        4A10AF9F time date stamp Sun May 17 17:45:19 2009
           ABA00 file pointer to symbol table
             EC4 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
              27 characteristics
                   Relocations stripped
                   Executable
                   Line numbers stripped
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
```

Comment: Those are Linux packages, right?  I would like to build and run on Windows.

Comment: Ahh, I just noticed a Windows build under the Automated Builds folder at the link you posted.  I think that will be exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm having trouble making this work. When I previously installed MinGW32, I used an installer. This is not an installer. I have added the bin folder to my path and it can find g++, but g++ has no idea where to look for the headers and libraries. When I used the installer, everything just worked.

Comment: It worked!  Initially I got the same error that I did when using the 64-bit prebuild drangon.com toolchain (cc1plus.exe crash) (see my comment in my question), so then I created a clean XP VM and did it there.  Bottom line, it finally worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options) say:

> These `-m' switches are supported in
>   addition to the above on AMD x86-64
>   processors in 64-bit environments.
>
> -m32
>   -m64 Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The 32-bit
>   environment sets int, long and pointer
>   to 32 bits and generates code that
>   runs on any i386 system. The 64-bit
>   environment sets int to 32 bits and
>   long and pointer to 64 bits and
>   generates code for AMD's x86-64
>   architecture.

Note that that's going to drive you crazy, I think, if mingw really does it that way, since normally on Windows 64 long is 32 bits and long long is the 64-bit pointer-sized
type.

Comment: I tried that in Cygwin and MinGW and they both complained that 64-bit mode is not compiled in.  That's pretty much what I expected to happen because I don't have the 64-bit version of either of those things.  That's what I'm trying to find.

Comment: The mingw gcc configured with --target=x86_64-pc-mingw32 produces code with sizeof(long) == 4 and sizeof(long long) == 8